Pixar's Curvenet system in Blender
For the past two weeks, I've been trying to replicate Pixar's Curvenet system in Blender. You can find a video of Curvenet on YouTube by searching "Curvenet Pixar" (the thumbnail features a red panda).
Specifically, I'm aiming to create deforming patches, such as a bending arm where the bicep muscle inflates via deformation handles. I'm trying to achieve this using the "Mesh Deform" modifier, but I'm encountering some issues.
When my armature deforms the object via "Mesh Deform," the bones corresponding to the deformation handles do not follow the pose in Pose Mode. If I parent the bone with "Keep Offset", it sometimes ends up misaligned from the vertex it’s supposed to be attached to. Using the Copy Location constraint allows the bone to follow the deformation precisely, but then the bone becomes unmovable in Pose Mode due to the Copy Location constraint.
I've tried other methods, including multiple armatures and transforming curves with empties, but none have been successful. I believe the method I described might be correct, but I’m struggling to make the deformation handle bone follow the vertex of the mesh deform in real-time (for animation purposes), while still allowing the handle bone to deform the cage when moved in Pose Mode.
Do you have any ideas or suggestions on how I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance!
Curvenet in action: https://youtu.be/gUJ4RxMdVn8?si=6mEQREZDUM4ShRlr&t=102
Without copy location: 
With copy location: 

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
